# how to retrieve data from a HashMap?

Tags: python, data-structures, hashmap

i'm trying to implemment a hash map, my code stores the keys and values but when trying to retrieve the value using the key it always returns None, i'm using python algorithms and data structure goodrich reference

```
from random import randrange

class MapBase:
    class item:
        def __init__(self,k,v):
            self.key = k
            self.value = v

        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.key == other.key

        def __ne__(self, other):
            return not self.key == other.key

        def __lt__(self, other):
            return self.key < other.key

class UnsortedMap(MapBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.size = 0

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        for i in self.data:
            if item == i.key:
                return i.value
        raise KeyError('Not Existing in the bucket')

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        item = self.item(key,value)
        for i in self.data:
            if key == i.key:
                i.value = value
                return
        self.data.append(item)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if len(self) == 0:
            raise KeyError('the map is empty')
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            if key == self.data[i].key:
                del self.data[i]
                return
        raise KeyError('The key doesnot exist in the map')

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.data:
            yield i
class HashMapBase(MapBase):
    def __init__(self,cap = 11, p = 109345121):
        self.data = cap*[None]
        self.n = 0
        self.prime = p
        self.scale = 1+ randrange(p-1)
        self.shift = randrange(self.prime)

    def hash_function(self,k):
        return (hash(k)*self.scale + self.shift) %self.prime %len(self.data)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n

    def items(self):
        for i in self.data:
            for item in i:
                yield item.key, item.value

    def resize(self,c):
        old = self.items()
        self.data = c*[None]
        self.n = 0
        for (k,v) in old:
            self.data[k] = v




    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        i = self.hash_function(key)
        self.bucket_setitem(i,key,value)
        if self.n > len(self.data) // 2:
            self.resize(2*len(self.data) -1)



    def __getitem__(self, key):
        i = self.hash_function(key)
        self.bucket_getitem(i,key)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.bucket_delitem(key)


class SeparateHashMap(HashMapBase):
    def bucket_setitem(self,i,key,value):
        if self.data[i] is None:
            self.data[i] = UnsortedMap()
        old_size = len(self.data[i])

        self.data[i][key] = value
        if len(self.data[i]) > old_size:
            self.n += 1
    def bucket_getitem(self,i,key):
        bucket = self.data[i]
        if bucket is None:
            raise KeyError("The bucket is empty")
        return bucket[key]

    def bucket_delitem(self,key):
        i = self.hash_function(key)
        for item in self.data[i]:
            if key == item.key:
                del item[i][key]
                return
        raise KeyError("The key doesn't exist")
    def __iter__(self):
        for bucket in self.data:
            if bucket is not None:
                for item in bucket:
                    yield item.key
```

this is my code and the implementation was just:

```
s = SeparateHashMap()
s[5] = 'v1'
s.__setitem__('key1','value1')
print(len(s))
for key in s:
    print(key)
    print(s.__getitem__(key))
```

and the results were 5  None  'key1'  None
i tried to reformat setitem and getitem but nothing changes the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to debug and visualize your code and it seems like there's an error within this code block. Bucket variable contains the correct value, however when the key is searched on the bucket it is returning none.

```py
106     def bucket_getitem(self,i,key):
107         bucket = self.data[i]
108         if bucket is None:
109             raise KeyError("The bucket is empty")
110         return bucket[key] #error is caused here
```

What I would advise you to do is to try and visualize the code [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) so that you can identify any illogical behaviour.